# Sort repeating numbers

Tags: c, sorting

```
 int a[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

What is the best approach to sort such series? Keep in mind I want the minimum complexity.

Comment: Are there only 0's, 1's and 2's?

Comment: this is illegal syntax first

Comment: You'll need to define "such series".  Do they all have only 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: not necessarily 0,1,2 but numbers in a very small range, in a large array.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The syntax is fine: `echo "int main() { int a[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; return 0; }" >test.c` then
`gcc test.c` runs fine.

Comment: @AlexNichol [question has been edited and corrected](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17867307/revisions)

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers have a small upper limit, you can use a counting sort: count how many times each item appears in the array, then walk through the array, and put in as many items as you counted for each of the values.

For example, in your case you would count 17 zeros, 7 ones, and 4 twos. Set the first 17 items to 0, the following 7 to 1, and the remaining 4 to 2 to get a sorted array.

This approach has linear complexity.

Comment: I was about to say , "Hash it and increment the occurence and sort the keys" ..which is what counting sort essentially does..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counting Sort` to sort such series.

Answer (score 2):

If the number series is truly limited to values 0-2 then the best thing to do is use a counted style sort.

```
void CountedSortMaxThree(int* array, size_t length) { 
  int count0 = 0;
  int count1 = 0;
  int count2 = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    switch(array[i]) {
      case 0: count0++; break; 
      case 1: count1++; break;
      case 2: count2++; break;
    }
  }

  int index = 0;
  while (count0-- > 0) array[index++] = 0;
  while (count1-- > 0) array[index++] = 1;
  while (count2-- > 0) array[index++] = 2;
}
```

To be re-usable you'd want to define an array of buckets equal to the max vs. the hard coded numbers

```
void CountedSort(int* array, int length, int max) { 
  int* buckets = malloc(sizeof(int) * max);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    bucket[array[i]]++;
  }

  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    while (buckets[i]-- > 0) {
      array[index++] = i;
    }
  }
  free(buckets);
}
```

Note that you should only use a counting sort when the range of values is small.  In your example the range is 3 (0 to 2 inclusive) hence ripe for counting sort.  If the range were much higher (think `Int32.Max`) then you'd end up allocating a giant bucket array which would end up being fairly inefficient

Comment: This is overly complex though, no? `count` should be an array... Also - this is technically called "counting sort", not "bucket sort" :)

Comment: @cluracan I was going for a specific answer and then adding in the more general purpose one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `qsort` function.

Comment: qsort is O(n*log(n)). With repeating numbers like this it should be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
void sort012Dutch(int A[],int n)
{
int pos0=0,pos2=n-1,i=0;
    while(i<n)
{
    if(A[i]==0)
    {
        A[i]=A[pos0];
        A[pos0]=0;
        pos0++;
    }
    if(A[i]==2&&i<pos2)
    {
        A[i]=A[pos2];
        A[pos2]=2;
        pos2--;
        i--;//0 could be swapped
    }
    i++;
}
}
```

pos0 indicates the next index in the array where 0 is to be inserted
pos2 indicates the next index in the array where 2 is to be inserted